# CancelKeyPress - accepting Input

Tags: c#, events, .net-core

When writing a Console Application, there aren't much EventHandlers which are concerning the Console Window, but I found out that one can use `System.Console.CancelKeyPress` to interrupt an ongoing process with an event.

Assuming the following program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += myHandler;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }



protected static void myHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        Console.WriteLine("  Cancel property: {0}", args.Cancel);
        Console.WriteLine("The read operation will resume...\n");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The program is printing "Hello World!" infinitely on the screen. And the interruption works, I assume they share a thread and for the split of a second it goes into the Handler method when you are pressing Ctrl + C. While it prints out on the screen the information about the current state of the cancel property, the Console.ReadLine() in the event gets completely omitted.

Is this intended behaviour to avoid blocking conflicts or is there a trick how one can read input when this event gets fired? Like type Y if you really want to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cancel event handler is indeed running on a different thread (verify this by printing out the thread id).

The main thread and the secondary thread running the event do not 'share a thread', but the do use the console output as a shared resource.

The readline in the event does not get omitted. Although the 'main' thread does indeed continue writing 'Hello World', if you press enter the event handler effectively reads the input you have entered.

If you want the main thread to 'pause' writing to the console, you have to find a mechanism to do just that.

Here is a very naive implementation:

```
    private static bool paused;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += myHandler;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!paused)
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    protected static void myHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        paused = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit?");
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        args.Cancel = answer != "y";
        paused = false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, that did indeed clarified why it is like it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you wish to do as follows ...

```
 class Program
{
    private static bool running = true;
    private static bool stop = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += myHandler;
        while (!stop)
        {
                if (running)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");                      
                } 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting ...");
    }



    protected static void myHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        running = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to resume... Y/N \n");
        var resume = Console.ReadLine();

        if (resume == "Y")
        {
            running = true;
        }
        else
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect event handler is running in a different context to the Console window main thread. I have not really used events in console windows before, but in WinForms the GUI  will be running on its own context thread.